# How to focus or select an item?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, select

What is the correct way to select a button in WinAPI so that the button or item has input focus indicated by the dotted lines? If i just set focus it is not selected. An example: I select an item index in a combobox via `CB_SETSEL`, how to select the complete item (dotted line, blue background)?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dialog, you should use the [`DM_SETDEFID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to make a push button the default. Simply calling `SetFocus` will give focus to a button (the "dotted lines") but won't make it the **default** button (the one that's actioned by pressing  the <kbd>Return</kbd> key). For example,

```
SendMessage(hwndDlg, DM_SETDEFID, IDC_BUTTON, 0);
```

For other types of controls, `SetFocus` is all you need, e.g:

```
SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_COMBO));
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'blue background' indicates the cell or list item is selected.  The 'dotted line' indicates that the cell or list item has the focus.  These are two different things that require two different method calls or messages.  In the style you are using, you have to send the CB_SETCURSEL message also.

http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/c/cb_setcursel.html